# Problem occurred when using PyTesseract to recognize text from an image

Tags: python, python-tesseract

I was trying to make an automatic login program for our school website, which requires recognizing text from a captcha code. So I installed `pytesseract` from pip, and ran the program in PyCharm: (the image is in the directory */Users/macintosh/Documents/PythonOutputs/2.jpg*)

---

```
import pytesseract

from PIL import Image

image = Image.open("/Users/macintosh/Documents/PythonOutputs/2.jpg")

text = pytesseract.image_to_string(image)

print(text)
```

---

But this error occured:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/Users/macintosh/Library/Preferences/PyCharmCE2018.2/scratches/scratch_3.py",
>   line 5, in 
>       text = pytesseract.image_to_string(image)
>
> File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py",
>   line 294, in image_to_string
>       return run_and_get_output(*args)
>
> File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py",
>   line 202, in run_and_get_output
>       run_tesseract(**kwargs)
>
> File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py",
>   line 178, in run_tesseract
>       raise TesseractError(status_code, get_errors(error_string))
>
> pytesseract.pytesseract.TesseractError: (2, 'Usage: python
>   pytesseract.py [-l lang] input_file')

What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Well, although your error message is not really crystal clear I bet (judging from your actions) you haven't installed [Tesseract](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract) itself.

In pytessaract documentation it states that:

> Python-tesseract is a wrapper for Google’s Tesseract-OCR Engine.

so you should install the actual program (Tesseract that is) to do the job also.